# Refresh code in browse button

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, button

I am working on a User interface where I use a browse button to get details from any of the text files given. I should display this text file details on a JTable and I need to refresh the code in the browse button of the User Interface. So that it goes back to its initial state of fetching data from the text files . I am using Swing GUI form-> Jframe form. Is it possible???

```
 private void btnBrowseActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    JFileChooser j = new JFileChooser();
    j.showOpenDialog(null);
    File f =j.getSelectedFile();
    String FileName = f.getAbsolutePath();
    txtFile.setText(FileName); 
    //table.removeAll();
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FileName))) {
        String sCurrentLine;
        int count =1;
        table = new JTable();
        DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel();{

        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if(count==1)
            {
                if(tableModel.getColumnCount()==0)
                {
                   tableModel.setColumnIdentifiers(sCurrentLine.split("\\t"));
                } 
            }
            else
            {
                tableModel.addRow(sCurrentLine.split("\\t"));
                //System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
            }
            count = count+1;
        }
    }
     table.setModel(tableModel);
     JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();  
     scrollPane.setBounds(10, 42, 604, 195);  
     scrollPane.setViewportView(table); 

     panel.add(scrollPane);
```

Comment: *"Is it possible"* - Yes.  Change the `TableModel` of the `JTable` with the model of the data you want shown. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: IMHO- You may want to put aside the form editors until you have a firm understanding how UI's are created and managed, it will give you a greater appreciation of when a form designer should be used and how to make the best use of them ;)

Comment: I "think" your problem is two fold, but I'm guessing based on an out-of-context snippet of code.  1: It looks like you're using a `null` (absolute) layout, this will make your life painful; 2: You seem to be adding a new `JScrollPane` to you view each time you click the button, when you should just be setting the table's model...

Comment: so what do you suggest? Can there be a better code to replace this ?

Comment: Or is it easier to just add a refresh code onto the existing code ? If so what code would seem fair ?

Comment: `JTable#setModel` should be all that's required, assuming the instance of  is already displayed on the screen

Comment: I actually have to use the browse button such a way that when I first browse a file its details are to be displayed in a table and when I click on the browse button again the whole data in the table should get refreshed and should simultaneously show me the file selected the second time.

Comment: If it is possible plz provide me with the code ASAP. I would really appreciate it. Thanks in advance